# Value assigned and not used in if statement

Tags: go

I wrote an example of the problem I'm seeing in go playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/rPCqAC56Ff

It's pretty self evident, but I'm declaring a variable outside of an if statement, setting variable in if and then using outside of if.

The question is simple, why doesn't this work?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var foo string
    if true {
        foo = "foo"
    } else {
        foo, found := os.LookupEnv("GOPATH")
        if !found {
            fmt.Printf("who cares.\n")
        }
    }
    println(foo)
}
```

Comment: From the documentation: "Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new. "

Comment: Check out @jussius answer. Clear explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Go documentation:

> An identifier declared in a block may be redeclared in an inner block.
>   While the identifier of the inner declaration is in scope, it denotes
>   the entity declared by the inner declaration.

:= in the else block redeclares foo, so that foo now refers to a whole new variable with the same name, a variable which is never used. Even if we somehow reached the else block, the println(foo) at last line wouldn't print our $GOPATH as that's stored to the other foo variable (or was until the whole variable went out of scope)

Correct code would be:

```
func main() {
    var foo string
    if true {
        foo = "foo"
    } else {
        var found bool
        foo, found = os.LookupEnv("GOPATH")
        if !found {
            fmt.Printf("who cares.\n")
        }
    }
    println(foo)
}
```

It's easy to get confused since this code works fine even though foo is redeclared before it used:

```
func main() {
    var foo string
    foo = "foo"
    foo, found := os.LookupEnv("GOPATH")
    if !found {
        fmt.Printf("who cares.\n")
    }
    println(foo)
}
```

What's happening here is that there's also another, different kind of legal redeclaration in Go:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration
>   may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier
>   in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function
>   body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables
>   is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a
>   multi-variable short declaration. **Redeclaration does not introduce a
>   new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.**

So in this other kind of redeclaration, no new foo variable is actually created and it works just like assignment to foo.

Comment: My take away from the documentation for the ":=" operator was that it declares variables only if they haven't been declared and sets previously declared variables as expected.  It looks like there's another layer of nuance with scoping I hadn't considered.  Your second example is good, because this is the typical use case and would naively suggest my given example to be "correct".

Answer (score 6):

You're creating a new variable `foo` in `if` *block*  with [`:=`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)

```
foo, found := os.LookupEnv("GOPATH")
```

Check [blocks](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks) and the scoping [rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope).

The correct [code](https://play.golang.org/p/MvfUFit9RA):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var foo string
    var found bool
    if true {
        foo = "foo"
    } else {
        foo, found = os.LookupEnv("GOPATH")
        if !found {
            fmt.Printf("who cares.\n")
        }
    }
    println(foo)
}
```

Comment: The documentation would suggest that this isn't the case: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

Comment: ...may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the **same block** (not the case @Dale)

Comment: Your code is correct, but the doc quote you posted is not actually what is happening here, as the redeclaration actually happens in a different block. Which, unlike short variable declarations in the same block, creates a whole new variable (which in this case is never used). See my answer for details.

Comment: You're right `redeclaring` was not the best word to define it. Thanks @jussius